# What is the added value of the documentation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the added value of the [documentation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/documentation) tag?

To me it is too generic and does not add any value. Could this be removed please?

Answer (score 8):

I disagree.

A large part of our job is ensuring that good documentation is in place. As such, questions about documentation methods, systems, ideas, etc. are perfectly on-topic, and warrant having their own tag.

That's not to say that current usage of the tag is appropriate. It may need some cleanup attention, but due to various other tag cleanup efforts that are ongoing, this may not be a high priority for those that choose to take on such tasks.